# How to copy a formula in excel without the cell number getting updated

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to achieve the following scenario.

1. value of G1 has formula set to (=F1)
2. When I copy the formula to other cells in column G, I want the formula to saty same (=F1) instead of dynamically getting updated to next cell number in the F column like (=F2) etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something like this you can use the $-symbol.

```
=$F$1
```

The $-symbol will take the following character as constant. So with the code above it will always refer to F1, no matter where you copy it.

Comment: Why in German?     ?

Comment: I was still tired I guess... as soon as I answered I realized that I wanted to answer in English... I hope it's showing in English now? (I edited it)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really for Stack Overflow but the answer is to use absolute references and so your formula would be =$F$2 and wherever you copy it, it would still refer to that cell.

Another way to do this would be with named cells, but absolute references is probably simpler.

Answer (score 0):

(For completeness of the previous answers)

As the previous posters noted, the `$` notation makes the reference absolute under cell copy.

Note that you can make the reference row coordinate and the column coordinate fixed independently, like $RC or R$C.

In order to streamline the `$`-ify reference process while writing the formula, use the `F4` function key after selecting that cell.

Cycling through the modes using F4 on, say, A10 reference, will change it to: $A$10 -> A$10 -> $A10 -> A10.